# Custom routes in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have a route that looks like this in `config/routes.rb`:

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'oauths#create'
```

`rake routes` shows me:

```
GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)                   oauths#create
```

And I'm writing an rspec test that starts out with:

```
describe OauthsController do
  describe '#create' do
    let(:request) { ->{post :create} }
    subject { request.call }
```

When running that test I get:

```
Failure/Error: let(:request) { ->{post :create} }
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"oauths", :action=>"create"}
```

How do I tell rspec the correct route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring the `:provider` parameter, you need to provide one :)

```
describe OauthsController do
  describe '#create' do
    let(:request) { ->{get( :create, :provider => 'some provider' )} }
    subject { request.call }
  end
end
```

And as @peter-alfvin noted, it's a GET not a POST.

Comment: The route is only defined for `get`, though, right? Will this `post` be handled?

Comment: Ah thanks! And yeah, I will switch it to `get`, I think I had changed it to `post` while trying to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution above but it did not work. I got:

```
ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: provider
```

It seems that RSpec now requires a `params` parameter. The corresponding call  looks like this:

```
get(:index, params: { provider: 1 })
```

Hope this helps!